# UITableView is getting interaction when changing rows with animation

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation

I have a tableview on a nib file with the interaction setting turned off. I'm animating a section change like this:

```
[myTableView beginUpdates];
[myTableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:YES];
[myTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:YES];
[myTableView endUpdates];
```

The problem is that, when I do this, the rows become selectable. How do I keep the interaction disabled while keeping the animation?

Answer (score 0):

use this

self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;